# Laplace of Gaussian in Harris Laplace Interest Point Detector

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, gaussian

In harris laplace interest point detector, we find LoG values at the interest points detected and then find the local extremum over the scale values for detecting the scale invariant points.

In the papers "Indexing base on scale invariant interest points" it is written that Laplacian of Gaussian is |(s^2)*(Lxx(x,s)+Lyy(x,s))|.

But when doing the code in matlab, I get output points when I don't take the absolute value of LoG but when I take its absolute value I don't get any output.

Can anyone say what is the problem?

Code:

`LoG = (sigI^2)*abs(fspecial('log',[5 5],sigI));
 imgLoG(:,:,n) = imfilter(img,LoG,'replicate','conv')`

sigI is the integration scale

Even tried:

`LoG = fspecial('log',[5 5],sigI);
 imgLoG(:,:,n) = (sigI^2)*abs(imfilter(img,LoG,'replicate','conv'))`

But no output.

Edit:

However, this code worked

`LoG = fspecial('log',[5 5],sigI);
 imgLoG(:,:,n) = (sigI^2)*imfilter(img,LoG,'replicate','conv')`

Answer (score 1):

The LoG is an High Pass filter.
Namely it has negative coefficients to work.

You code mitigates its negative values.